# How to generate a pass from 2 different json_encodes

Tags: php, json, passbook

I use this method to generate a pass:

```
 public function setJSON($JSON) {
    if(json_decode($JSON) !== false) {
        $this->JSON = $JSON;
        return true;
    }
    $this->sError = 'This is not a JSON string.';
    return false;
    }
```

I call this method to generate pass by:

```
$pass->setJSON('{
    "passTypeIdentifier": "'.$passTypeID.'",
    "formatVersion": 1,
    ..............
"barcode": {
        "altText" : "'.$alt.'",
        "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
        "message": "Member-Card",
        "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
        "changeMessage" : "This pass now has altText  %@ !"
        },
"locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89529371261597,
      "latitude" : 11.576150037278605,
      "relevantText": "CamMob (dis. 1%)"
    },
     .....................
]
    }');
```

But now I don't write those locations statically and I get those data from database by  :

```
$query5 = mysql_query("select * from company");
    while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($query5)){
        $companyName = $row5['relevantTextName'];
        $discount = $row5['relevantTextDiscount'];
        $long = $row5['longitute'];
        $lat = $row5['latitute'];
        $link = $row5['link'];
```

`$location['locations'][] = array("longitute" => $long, "latitute" => $lat, "relevantText" => $companyName." (" . $discount. "%)" );
}
$jsonString = json_encode($location) ;

error_log("Locations: ".$jsonString,0);
$pass->setJSON($jsonString);

$pass->setJSON('{
"passTypeIdentifier": "'.$passTypeID.'",

    "barcode": {
    "altText" : "'.$alt.'",
    "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
    "message": "Member-Card",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
    "changeMessage" : "This pass now has altText  %@ !"
    }       
}');</pre>`

There is no error when I test for updating pass, but I cannot see the pass on lock screen like before. Thus it means that I not yet include those locations to the pass. What should I change ? Is it the problem of method setJSON ? If I do like this, how can I combine these 2 jsons to become together  ?

Comment: How many locations do you have? Remember that only the first 10 will show. Also, if you want to verify whether the locations are being added to the JSON you can change the extension of the .pkpass file to .zip to see what your code is generating, or alternatively write the JSON to the php log.

Comment: If I select location from database, how can I add  them by encoding to the pass that is already created ?

Comment: I don't know how to combine different encode_json !

Comment: I try this: .............."locations": '.$jsonString.'
    
   }');

Comment: Then I get this error: [10-May-2013 04:25:52 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-10 09:25:54 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 7, if-modified-since Fri, 10 May 2013 09:14:33 GMT + 7; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.)

Comment: I also try this:    array_push($pass, $jsonString);//line 159
but I get this error: [10-May-2013 09:53:59 Asia/Phnom_Penh] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/webService/getPassUpdated.php on line 159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than constructing the JSON directly, construct an array first, then transform it into JSON.

```
$pass_data = array("passTypeIdentifier" => $passTypeID,
                   "formatVersion" => 1,
                   "barcode" => array (
                                       "altText" => $alt,
                                       "format" => "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
                                       "message" => "Member-Card",
                                       "messageEncoding" => "utf-8", // use UTF8 in case you want to encode Khmer or other non ASCII 
                                       "changeMessage" => "This pass now has altText  %@ !"
                                      ), 
                   "locations" => $locationsArray,
                   "organizationName" => "Digi club card",
                   "description" => "Membership card",
                   "logoText" => "Digiclub",
                   "foregroundColor" => "rgb(0,0,0)",
                   "backgroundColor" => "rgb(211,211,211)",
                   "generic" => array (
                            "headerFields" => array(
                                       array ( "key" => "Status",
                                               "label" => " ",
                                               "value" => "Membership card"
                                             ),
                                       ),
                            "primaryFields" => array(
                                       array ( "key" => "Name",
                                               "value" => $memberName,
                                             ),
                                       ),

                            "secondaryFields" => array(
                                      // Secondary Field data
                                       ),

                            "auxiliaryFields" => array(
                                      // Auxiliary Field data
                                       ),

                            "backFields" => array(
                                      // Backfiels Field data
                                       ),
                           )
                    );
```

Then transform the array into JSON:

```
$pass->setJSON(json_encode($pass_data));
```

Comment: Thank you, I just test in this way too, but I don't write all to array, instead I use decode, but I also met some errors !

Comment: $dataArray = json_decode($data,true);
 $result = array_merge($dataArray,$location);
    $String = json_encode($result); 
 error_log("All data: ".$String,0);

Comment: [10-May-2013 10:55:32 Asia/Phnom_Penh] All data: {"passTypeIdentifier":"pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest","formatVersion":1,"serialNumber":"7","teamIdentifier":"3J29YP53Q5","authenticationToken":"Fy7Iiew81JNdsdaG","webServiceURL":"http:\/\/192.168.1.202\/passesWebserver\/webService\/","associatedStoreIdentifiers":[485596906],

Comment: error: 
 [10-May-2013 05:55:32 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-10 10:55:33 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 7, if-modified-since Fri, 10 May 2013 10:10:34 GMT + 7; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.)

Comment: Just use the revised code above.  Writing JSON, decoding it then re-encoding it is very inefficient.

Comment: what about this (in barcodeField):                                        "message" :"MemberName:".$name.' ID: "'.$ID.'" ?

Comment: it has both string and variable !

Comment: I just got this error after writing like like you: [10-May-2013 06:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/webService/getPassUpdated.php on line 88
//line88:"formatVersion": 1,

Comment: but now I also get this error : [10-May-2013 07:00:08 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-10 12:00:10 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 7, if-modified-since Fri, 10 May 2013 10:10:34 GMT + 7; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.)

Comment: Just noticed an error with the nested arrays for the field items.  Try the updated code above.  Also look at the JSON outputted (use [a Javascript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org)) to format it to see what part of the array is causing the error.

Comment: before I wrote: $pass->setJSON('{......}') and result of json_encode($pass_data) is {"passTypeIdentifier": .........}

Comment: so $pass->setJSON(json_encode($pass_data)); is same as $pass->setJSON('{.......}'); ?

Comment: `json_encode($pass_data)` outputs a JSON string, so yes, it should have the same effect as passing the JSON directly to that method. You should remove any other calls to `$pass->setJSON` because this method should be only called once.

Comment: [10-May-2013 13:20:15 Asia/Phnom_Penh] All data: {"passTypeIdentifier":"pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest","formatVersion":1,"serialNumber":"7","teamIdentifier":"3J29YP53Q5","authenticationToken":"Fy7Iiew81JNdsdaG","webServiceURL":"http:\/\/192.168.1.202\/passesWebserver\/webService\/","associatedStoreIdentifiers":[485596906],"foregroundColor":"rgb(0,0,0)","backgroundColor":"rgb(230,230,250)","logoText":"DigiClub","organizationName":"Digi Club Card","description":"Digi company","generic":{"headerFields":[{"key":"Status","label":" ","value":"Membership card"}],

Comment: "primaryFields":[{"key":"Name","label":"Name","value":"Urina"}],"secondaryFields":[{"key":"ID","label":"Member ID","value":"7"},{"key":"date","label":"Just Update On","value":"10\/05\/13, 1:20 PM"}],"auxiliaryFields":[{"key":" ","label":"Power By","value":"Yata","changeMessage":"This pass is now powered by %@ !"}],

Comment: "backFields":[{"key":"partners & discount","label":"Discount price from partners of Digi","value":"- CamMob (1%)\r\n      long.: 104.89529371261597\r\n      lat.: 11.576150037278605\r\n- ITC (2%)\r\n      long.: 104.89823341369629\r\n      lat.: 11.570705493829758\r\n- Digi (10%)\r\n      long.:

Comment: ............."},{"key":"terms","label":"TERMS AND CONDITIONS","value":"The holder of this card is authorized to receive and use benefits, privileges, discounts on the terms and conditions set out by Digi (DTV STAR Co., Ltd.). \r\nFor details: 077\/023 22 77 66 | care@digi.com.kh |\r\nhttp:\/\/www.digi.com.kh\/digiclub. \r\nThis card is property of Digi. If found, please return to any office of Digi. It is non-transferable and may be revoked by Digi at any time without prior notice."}]},

Comment: "barcode":{"altText":"asfdf","format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417","message":"Barcode Message","messageEncoding":"utf-8","changeMessage":"This pass now has altText  %@ !"},"locations":

Comment: [{"longitute":"104.89529371261597","latitute":"11.576150037278605","relevantText":"CamMob (1%)"},{"longitute":"104.89823341369629","latitute":"11.570705493829758","relevantText":"ITC (2%)"},................, {"longitute":"104.89523202180862","latitute":"11.569042154169637","relevantText":"EZECOM (30.35%)"}]}

Comment: If you want to post lots of code, then please use pastebin.com (E.g. http://pastebin.com/T4ana3Et